# Build project to EAR in eclipse

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My project is running absolutely perfect in local computer. And could deploy the WebSphere server successfully. But when I amend some of the content of the ireport files with the extension .jrxml, the EAR do not get updated. I have search around the web and cannot find a way to fix it.

Comment: are you sure the `.jrxml` file which u amended the changes is in the same location of EAR? are u getting any errors?

Comment: I am sure the .jrxml is the same location of EAR. And the EAR is no problem. My colleague use it to run it his local machine. It works fine.But when deploy the Websphere, the .jrxml just not updated. I don't know why.